# Не получается создать структуру которая внутри будет добавлять объект в массив

Tags: swift, static

такой вариант

```
struct SwimmingWorkout {
enum Stroke {
    case freestyle, butterfly
}
var distance : Double
var time: Double
var stroke: Stroke
var freestyleArray : [SwimmingWorkout] = []
var butterflyArray : [SwimmingWorkout] = []

mutating func saveToArray () {
    switch stroke {
    case .freestyle : freestyleArray.append(self)
    case .butterfly : butterflyArray.append(self)
    }
}
```

}

но он оне верный. подскажите как правильно

Answer (score 0):

почему не верный?

просто надо создать экземпляр структуры

можно создать внутри структуры конструктор, можно вот так:

```
var test = SwimmingWorkout(stroke: .butterfly, freestyleArray: [], butterflyArray : [])
```

затем вызвать метод

```
test.saveToArray()
```